# How to prevent an element with scroll-y and scroll-x to be moved freely on mobile version on touch events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have an element which has `overflow: scroll` both on `y` and `x` axes, however when the element is on mobile version it has a weird touch behavior, it allows the user not only to move the element horizontally and vertically, but also to any other direction, like diagonally, for example.

I'd like to make it respect the axes and only move `up-down/down-up` and `right-left/left-rigth`.

How could I fix this?

I added a snippet, but I got this example from [Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/touch-action/#:%7E:text=pan%2Dx%20%3A%20Enables%20horizontal%20panning,with%20a%20single%20finger%20interaction.). It can be seen on mobile version with multiple versions of `touch-action`, none of them satisfied what I need to do.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.map {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.map img {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
 } 
.map-desc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 130px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.touch-auto {
  touch-action: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="map touch-auto">
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526778548025-fa2f459cd5c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
<code class="map-desc">touch-action: auto;</code>
</div>
```